# Skip first 3 lines of while loop

Tags: linux, bash

I have this code.

```
while IFS= read
do
    read -r
    read -r
    read -r

    echo $REPLY

done <<< "$LINES"
```

and data in LINES:

```
----
Test
---- 
1,2,3 
1,2,4 
etc
```

I want to skip first 3 lines and start process only at line 4 onwards.
I tried read -r but seems not working. I want output:

```
1,2,3 
1,2,4 
etc
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/289160/283843

Comment: Move the initial `read` statements outside your loop, so they only happen once. But there are better solutions if you read around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more bash specific syntax.

```
i=3 n=0
while read -r line; do
  ((n >= i )) && echo "$line"
  ((n++))
done < file
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering that the content of the variable is similar as mentioned, reading the data from 4th line of `$LINE` is the one of solutions. That can be done like this,

```
tail +4 <<< "$LINE"
```

This prints every line from 4th line of `$LINE` till last line is encountered.

If you want its result to be used inside `while`, this does a better job,

`while IFS= read -r; do echo $REPLY; done <<< "$(tail +4 <<< "$LINE")"`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to do with the lines, but if you can wrap it in a *callback* and have bash version 4+ then you could use `mapfile` (or its synonym `readarray`) with its `-s` (skip) option.

Ex. given

```
$ echo "$LINES"
----
Test
---- 
1,2,3 
1,2,4 
etc
```

then after defining

```
myfunc() { printf "%s\n" "$2"; }
```

you can do

```
$ mapfile -t -s3 -c1 -C 'myfunc' <<< "$LINES"
1,2,3 
1,2,4 
etc
```

Comment: Unfortunately bash3 users (hint mac/apple) does not have mapfile aka readarray so it is worth mentioning that this is a bash4+ feature.

Comment: @Jetchisel thanks - noted